# FIlter based on array inside Object in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Hi i am using mongoose to create an object which has a field with type object. The object has two more fields start_date and end_date. Now i get a query which should filter out the records which don't conincide with any of the start_date to end_date period. That is (either query_end_date < start_date or query_start_date > end_date)

```
type : [{
            userId : {
                type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
                required : true
            },
            startDate : {
                type : Date,
                required : true
            },
            endDate : {
                type : Date,
                required : true
            }   
        }]
```

Comment: I guess startDate and endDate are subdocuments, do you want to filter only the documents based on the conditions in subdocuments or you want to also filter the subdocuments? Please specify sample input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a query with the `$gt` and `$lt` operators and the syntax for querying array of nested documents:

```js
async function Query(query_start_date, query_end_date){
  try{
    let users = await Model.find({ $or: [{ "field.startDate" : { $gt : query_end_date}} ,
                                   {"field.endDate" : { $lt : query_start_date}} });
    console.log(users);
  } catch(err){
    console.log("Error ", err);
  }
```

[Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/)

Comment: But will this search over all the arrays in the field.startDate ?

Comment: Also i wanted the date not inside the interval of startDate and endDate, i wanted it outside of that interval.

Comment: Ok I have modified the answer, does it work for you?

Comment: Yes , i figured it out myself later, i wrote exact same query. Thanks for your help.